# Eighth order moment

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, moments

I read Nonlinear Dimensionality Reduction by Lee and Verleysen [[Google Books](http://books.google.si/books?id=o_TIoyeO7AsC&lpg=PA8&ots=CMId9rg3Iu&dq=finite%20eight%20order%20moment%20identically%20distributed&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q=finite%20eight%20order%20moment%20identically%20distributed&f=false)] and came across the following theorem (p. 8):

> Let $\mathbf{y}$ be a $D$-dimensional vector $[y_1, \ldots, y_d, \ldots,y_D]'$; all components $y_d$ of the vector are i.i.d. with a finite eighth order moment.

Can anyone please explain what the authors mean by "finite eighth order moment"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the language on the theorem, he's clearly referring to a **random** $D$-dimensional vector. This means that each $y_d$ is a random variable; for the sake of notation lets denote it by $Y_d$ (I really hate when authors don't do the distinction). With that said, the $n$-th order moment about $x_0$ of $Y_d$ is defined as:
$$\mathbb{E}[(Y_d-x_0)^n]=\int(y_d-x_0)^nf_{Y_d}(y_d)dy_d,$$
where $f_{Y_d}(y_d)$ is the probability density function of the random variable $Y_d$. Having finite eight order moment means that
$$\mathbb{E}[(Y_d-x_0)^8]=\int(y_d-x_0)^8f_{Y_d}(y_d)dy_d<\infty,$$
for some $x_0$. It is usual, however, to define the $n$-th order moment as the moment about $x_0=\mathbb{E}[Y_d]$, and assume zero-mean random variables, i.e., assume that $\mathbb{E}[Y_d]=0$ which would imply that what the authors meant was that
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_d^8]=\int y_d^8f_{Y_d}(y_d)dy_d<\infty.$$

Comment: It may be worth observing that the finiteness of any even moment around any center $x_0$ implies the finiteness of that moment around any other center: that is why it is unnecessary to specify the center.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for your comment @whuber! I think what I really wanted to state was the difference between a moment and a central moment but, as you say, this is unnecessary for the definition in this case.